# How can I call hundreds of PHP pages from my browser?

Tags: php

So here's my situation:

I moderate a forum with a fairly dumb control panel. There is a list of reports (spam etc), and beside each entry there is a "mark as read" button. The thing is, there is no such thing as a "mark all as read" button. You have to manually click each of the hundreds of buttons there.

I have noticed that the buttons open PHP pages with the following scheme:

```
http://www.example.com/mark_as_read.php?id=1
http://www.example.com/mark_as_read.php?id=2
http://www.example.com/mark_as_read.php?id=3
...
http://www.example.com/mark_as_read.php?id=100
```

As you can see, the only thing that changes is the `ID` parameter.

I was under the impression that I could, somehow, do some sort of batch call.

Now, I'm not any sort of web programmer. However I know how to send HTTP requests to websites using, say, Java. So I went ahead and wrote a little program that calls that link 100 times (increasing the ID number each iteration).

It doesn't work, because you need to be authenticated as a moderator. The website determines this by the browser's cookies. I don't know much about that, so I just discarded my Java solution.

It would seem like I require to do these calls from my browser, so that the website can use my cookies to allow the operation.

How can I achieve this? How can I call hundreds of PHP pages from my browser?

---

Some notes:

- I don't own the website, and don't have access to their internals.
- I can use any browser alright. Chrome/Safari/IE.
- The PHP call will not work if you're not authenticated (so you need to use the browser).
- I'm not interested in the PHP output of the calls. I just want the PHP code to execute.
- It would be great to not have 100 tabs open in my browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need a quick and dirty solution, you can inject a few JavaScript functions into your browsers JavaScript console.

Pardon the verboseness - it's compiled CoffeeScript.

```
var mark_all_as_read, mark_as_read;

mark_as_read = function(id) {
  var request;
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("get", "http://www.example.com/mark_as_read.php?id=" + id);
  return request.send();
};

mark_all_as_read = function(ids) {
  var id, _i, _len, _results;
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = ids.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    id = ids[_i];
    _results.push(mark_as_read(id));
  }
  return _results;
};
```

Now you should be able to call `mark_as_read(123)` or `mark_all_as_read([123, 456])` from your console.

Beware that your webhost might not approve of you sending hundreds of requests simultanously. In that case, you can add the third parameter `false` the `request.open` method call. This will slow down the loop dramatically by waiting for each request to finish before performing the next request.

Answer (score 0):

Write a Chrome plugin that does this for you. A plugin is basically a piece of Javascript that runs in the scope of the page your are in, so you can easily read the list of items and call the url. I think (but I'm not sure) that any ajax requests performed by your plug-in also are run within the scope of the page and are therefor not affected by same origin policy.

You need some boilerplate code, but fortunately, there are plenty of tutorials to get you started:

- Google/Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted
- Lifehacker: http://lifehacker.com/5857721/how-to-build-a-chrome-extension

You don't have to register your plugin if it's just for you. You can just install it from the source you made:

- http://lifehacker.com/5919997/how-to-install-extensions-that-arent-from-the-official-chrome-web-store

Otherwise you might open the reports in a separate tab. Maybe it is inconvenient, but most browsers have a 'close all tabs on the right of this tab', so you can close all of them in two clicks.